# How to navigate a subframe inside a frameset using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, frame

I need to get the result from the table "td". But before I can do that I need to navigate a frame that contains it. The frame is one of the frameset elements that belongs to the mainFrame. I tried to use all types of navigating the "child" subframe non of which works:

```
 driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
     driver.switchTo().frame("mainFrame.0.fr_resultsNav~ResultsMaxGroupTemplate0.9766101221774707");
    driver.switchTo().frame("main.Frame.1.fr_resultsNav~ResultsMaxGroupTemplate0.8811790466176727");

// even: driver.switchTo().frame("mainFrame.0.fs_main");
```

The following is the brief layout of the webpage:

```
<frame src="banner.asp" name="topFrame" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" id="topFrame" title="topFrame">

<frame src="" name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" title="mainFrame" wd_frame_id_="5f4c10bc7e0960070bfda831655b8b0c">

    <frameset id="fs_main" border="0" frameborder="no" framespacing="0" rows="70,87,*">
.....................

        <frameset id="fs_content" cols="23%,*" framespacing="0" frameborder="no">
.....................
            <frameset cols="*,9" id="LeftFrameSet" framespacing="0" frameborder="no">
.....................
            <frame frameborder="0" name="fr_classification~ResultsMaxGroupTemplate0.609021034867735" title="Results Classification Frame" id="fr_classification~ResultsMaxGroupTemplate0.609021034867735" src="/lnacui2api/results/shared/waitMessage.do?wmibIdRand=61_T16938265013_rand_1363544453847" scrolling="Auto" onload="paintResultsBorder('ResultsMaxGroupTemplate0.609021034867735');">

....................

<form name="results_listview_ResultsListForm" method="post" action="/lnacui2api/results/listview/listview.do" id="results_listview_ResultsListForm">

..........

<td nowrap="" height="20"> <span id="new">&nbsp;All Results</span> (294)</td>
</form>

....................
```

Do I need to navigate the frameset before I can navigate a subframe? I read the documentation. All internet examples give a simple sample code: driver.switchTo().frame("mainFrame.0.child"). It does not work in this case. Please, take a look at the above script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree, you cannot directly switch to a child frame. Also, make sure to switch to the `defaultContent` (`driver.switchTo.defaultContent`) every time you want to switch frame. With regard to your example, `driver.switchTo().frame("mainFrame.0.child")` --- this could also work, but you need to get rid of unnecessary quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks!  Switching back to the default content before switching to a new frame is key.  For anyone working in python, the corresponding method is: `driver.switch_to_default_content()`

Comment: @CHEBURASHKA, link is not working. Can you please update?

Answer (score 8):

Find the index of main frame starting from zero then use

```
driver.switchTo.frame(mainFrameindex);
```

Then find the index of sub frame in the main frame

```
driver.switchTo.frame(subFrameIndex);
```

You cannot directly switch to a child frame without first switching to the parent frame. This is how it works.

Comment: will this work with IFrames? I have a list of both mixed:
List<WebElement> frames = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe"));
 frames.addAll(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//frame")));

Answer (score 3):

Through chaining methods together, once you `switchTo().defaultContent`, you can create temporary lists of available frames through findElements() by tagName and go to that specific frames' index...

For example

```
driver.switchTo()defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("frameset")).findElements(By.tagName("frame")).get(2));
```

Comment: worked for me.! In my case I need to locate to nested frame:
 driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("frameset")).findElements(By.tagName("frame")).get(1)); // switch to the second frame in  main page
       driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("frameset")).findElements(By.tagName("frame")).get(0)); //switch to the nested frame

Answer (score 1):

You can switch directly to the frame you want with the xPath.
Get the Xpath through the Developer console, then:

`driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('html / frameset / frameset / frame[1]'))`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. The course I'm taking tells you cannot do that. Others on similar questions say you cannot do that. My trials seem to go this way.

Comment: I also find that this does NOT work.... my target is of the form: `html/frameset/frameset[1]/frame[2]`.