# Python Selenium Webdriver - Navigating nested frame sets

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working on a page with nested frames, and am unable to access a child frame. Brief outline of HTML source:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <frameset id="0">
        <frame name="name">
        <frameset cols="10%,20%" id="01">
            <frame name="mid1">
            <frame name="mid2" scrolling="auto" src="chkclineversion.asp" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"> 
        </frameset>
        <frame name="bot">
    </frameset>
</html>
```

I need to access the frame named "mid2". This frame is nested within a frameset which is in turn nested within the main frameset.

I've tried the following codes but they do work

```
driver.switch_to_frame("mid2") #direct reference to nested frame name

driver.switch_to_frame(1)
driver.switch_to_frame("mid2") #switch to subframe by index and then attempt to reference "mid2". This gives me a no such frame exception1
```

Am I missing something obvious?

I've checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464808/how-to-navigate-a-subframe-inside-a-frameset-using-selenium-webdriver) but it does not clarify my question.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
driver.switch_to_frame("name")
driver.switch_to_frame("mid2")
```

The issue you're running into is that javascript can only work with the current frame it sees.  `mid2` is in a child frame it cannot see if you're at the top of the document.

Comment: Thanks. The issue though is that the frame 'name' is not the parent frame of 'mid2'. 'mid2' is part of the sub-frameset with id '01'.

Answer (score 2):

The `<frame>` tag with `name` as **mid2** seems to be nested within 2 additional layers of `<frame>`.

to access the `<frame>` with `name` attribute as **mid2** you have to:

- Ignore (safely) the presence of *parent* / *child* `<frameset>` tags.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the first layer of `<frame>` to be available and switch to it.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the second layer of `<frame>` to be available and switch to it.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `<frame>` to be available and switch to it.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"name")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"frame[name='mid1']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//frame[@name='mid2' and starts-with(@src, 'chkclineversion')]")))
    ```
  - **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to locate and click on an element which is nested within multiple frame and frameset through Selenium using Webdriver and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798937/how-to-locate-and-click-on-an-element-which-is-nested-within-multiple-frame-and/50813825#50813825)

---

### Outro

- [How can I select a html element no matter what frame it is in in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium/47771879#47771879)
- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478)