# No Frame found in Selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using following code for find the iframe in a web page

```
string win = diver.CurrentWindowHandle;
driver.switchTo().Window(win);
driver.switchTO().defautContent();
```

Then I tried with the following things but still I got the NO frame found error.

```
driver.switchTo().Frame(1); (or)
driver.switchTo().Frame(0);
driver.switchTo().Frame(driver.findelement(by.id(By.xpath("//xpath of d frame")))
driver.switchTo().Frame(driver.findelement(by.id(By.tagname(iframe)))
driver.switchTo().Frame(driver.findelement(by.id(By.className(classnamehere)))
```

[Please click here to view the HTML structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5ula.png)

Comment: can you try `driver.switchTo.Frame("contentIFrame0")`

Comment: @NarendraR yes .. I already tried that too.. same its throwing NosuchFrameException

Comment: can share the site URL

Comment: it will open inside the client machine only

Comment: I guess there is some glitch while you are switching first window and then frame. is is opening 2 windows ? and you are switching in second window and the switching in iframe in that seconds window ?

Comment: its not opening two separate windows .first step I'm  opening the record and click on button which is available in new window.after clicking its generating our target iframes in the same window itself

Comment: then why you are switching the window. just comment the switching window code and try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select a html element no matter what frame it is in in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium/47771879#47771879)

Comment: @NarendraR still there is no luck.

Comment: @DebanjanB I dono why you make this question as duplicate.That mentioned question is belongs to python.But its c# and more over I tried all the ways but I didn't achieve.

Comment: You need to share the relevant `HTML` for SO volunteers to help you out. Switching frames doesn't needs the `window_handles` as such.

Comment: @DebanjanB I already added the html structure in the question itself.

Comment: Instead of adding snapshots of `html structure` can you add the `HTML` as a formatted text? Which `iframe` do you want to switchover?

Comment: @DebanjanB I completely agree your point to post a code instead of image.But I'm not able to copied the code from client machine.In client machine there is no internet connection.so tat I posted as a image. I want to shift **contentIFrame1**

Answer (score 0):

Let us analyze whats happening in your code :

- Code Attempt 1:

  ```
  string win = diver.CurrentWindowHandle;
  driver.switchTo().Window(win);
  ```

  All the frames remains attached to the same **`windowHandle`**. So `driver.switchTo().Window(win);` is not a choice.
- Code Attempt 2:

  ```
  driver.switchTo().Frame(1);
  driver.switchTo().Frame(0);
  ```

  As we are not sure of the loading sequence of the `frames`, trying to switch frames through **`index`** may not help us.
- Code Attempt 3:

  ```
  driver.switchTo().Frame(driver.findelement(by.id(By.xpath("//xpath of d frame")))
  ```

  This should have worked provided we had supplied a valid and unique **`xpath`** of the `frame`.
- Code Attempt 4:

  ```
  driver.switchTo().Frame(driver.findelement(by.id(By.tagname(iframe)))
  ```

  This will try to switch to the first available `iframe` which may not be the intended one or visible at all. Hence **Fails**.
- Code Attempt 5:

  ```
  driver.switchTo().Frame("contentIFrame0");
  ```

  This option wouldn't work straight away as the **`visibility`** attribute is set to **`hidden`**
- Code Attempt 6:

  ```
  driver.switchTo().Frame("contentIFrame1");
  ```

  This option must work but from the `HTML` which you have shared the `WebElements` are not clear.

Comment: I use the following codes `driver.SwitchTo().ParentFrame();driver.SwitchTo().defaultContent();driver.findelements(by.tagname("iframe"))` . Now Im getting  32 digit unique frame ids.

Comment: Is possible to get the elements which is inside the frame, by using this frame ids?