# Skip waiting for a website timer selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm running Selenium in Python ide with geckodriver.

The site I'm trying to open has a timer of 30 seconds that after this 30 seconds a button appears and I send a click on it.

What I'm asking is the following:
Can I somehow ignore/skip/speed up the waiting time?

Right now what I'm doing is the following:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("SITE_URL")
sleep(30)
driver.find_element_by_id("proceed").click()
```

Which is very inefficient because every time I run the code to do some tests I need to wait.

Thanks in advance, Avi.

*UPDATE:*
I haven't found a way to get over the obstacle but until I do I'm trying to focus the next achievable progress:

```
<video class="jw-video jw-reset" disableremoteplayback="" webkit-playsinline="" playsinline="" preload="metadata" src="//SITE.SITE.SITE/SITE/480/213925.mp4?token=jbavPPLqNqkQT1SEUt4crg&amp;time=1525458550" style="object-fit: fill;"></video>
```

(censored site's name)

In each page there is a video, all the videos are under the class "jw-video jw-reset"
I had trouble using find element by class so I used:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "video[class='jw-video jw-reset']")))
```

It works but I can't figure how to select the element's src...

Comment: Well obviously you have to find out how the website does the 30 second delay and find out how to influence it. It's not going to happen in your code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your code trial you can remove the `time.sleep(30)` and induce *WebDriverWait* for the element to be clickable as follows :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# lines of code
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "proceed"))).click()
```

**Note** : Configure the *WebDriverWait* instance with the maximum time limit as per your usecase. The `expected_conditions` method `element_to_be_clickable()` will return the *WebElement* as soon as the element is **visible** and **enabled** such that you can click it.

Comment: Thanks!
WebDriverWait is very helpful!