# How does Selenium WebDriver cope with heavy traffic on website?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I wrote a script to automate the action of carting a product and checking out on selenium. I was wondering how heavy site traffic (aka site crashing) will be handled on selenium's end? I assume this is normal as a regular browser?

Are there any fallbacks that should be implemented in the code for this (e.g. checking timeouts, status codes)? Running headless if it matters.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is *immutable* to *site traffic* or the *load* on the *AUT (Application Under Test)*

### So what matters for Selenium and WebDriver

The following aspects should be part of the *best practices* when working with *Selenium*:

- If you are having any issue with initial *Page Loading* tweak the **pageLoadStrategy**.
- You can find a detailed discussion on **pageLoadStrategy** in [How to make Selenium not wait till full page load, which has a slow script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770796/how-to-make-selenium-not-wait-till-full-page-load-which-has-a-slow-script)
- Remove all the instances of **`time.sleep(n)`** to increase stability.
- You can find a detailed discussion on **time.sleep(n)** in [How to sleep webdriver in python for milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds)
- **Implicit Wait** was a good way to start with to deal with dynamic elements but may soon die in fire.
- You can find a detailed discussion on **Implicit Wait** in [Using implicit wait in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672693/using-implicit-wait-in-selenium)
- If AUT (Application Under Tests) is built with [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/), [AngularJS](https://angular.io/), [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/), [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/) **Explicit Wait** would be your best bet.
- You can find a detailed discussion on **Explicit Wait** in [Skip waiting for a website timer selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168663/skip-waiting-for-a-website-timer-selenium-python)