# Unable to fill the form using Selenium: AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'get_element_by_xpath'

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to fill the Uber [form](https://m.uber.com/looking)
using selenium.

It looks like this:

[image]

I tried to use `XPath` to fill the form, here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Zedas\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
w.get("https://m.uber.com/looking")
time.sleep(6)
w.get_element_by_xpath(f'"//*[@id="booking-experience-container"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/input"').send_keys("test")
```

But, this is the error:

```
w.get_element_by_xpath(f'"//*[@id="booking-experience-container"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/input"').send_keys("test")
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'get_element_by_xpath'
```

How can this error be fixed?

Answer (score 3):

There's no method known as `get_element_by_xpath` in Selenium-Python bindings.

Please use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath here")
```

Also, Since `find_element` internally looks for implicit waits to wait and interact with web element. Often, It has been observed that it is not a consistent method to look for web element/elements in Selenium automation.

Please use **Explicit waits :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "xpath here"))).send_keys("test")
```

You will need these imports as well.

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

You can read more about waits from [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait)

Answer (score 2):

Selenium just removed find_element_by_xpath() in version 4.3.0

now, it should be
`driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]div[1]/input')`

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/a4995e2c096239b42c373f26498a6c9bb4f2b3e7/py/CHANGES

Answer (score 1):

`w.get_element_by_xpath` should be `w.find_element_by_xpath`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Zedas\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
w.get("https://m.uber.com/looking")
time.sleep(6)
w.find_element_by_xpath(f'"//*[@id="booking-experience-container"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/input"').send_keys("test")
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
w.get_element_by_xpath(f'"//*[@id="booking-experience-container"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/input"').send_keys("test")
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'get_element_by_xpath'
```

implies that the [*WebDriver*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) object has no attribute as `get_element_by_xpath`.

---

You have to take care of a couple of things as follows:

- If you look at the various [*WebDriver*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727887/what-is-benefit-of-using-chromedriver-over-webdriver-if-we-are-using-only-chrome/53744026#53744026) strategies to [*locate elements*](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) there is no method as `get_element_by_xpath()` and possibly you would like to replace with `find_element_by_xpath()`
- While invoking `click()` on an element, [*Implicit Wait*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53588966/python-selenium-difference-between-driver-implicitly-wait-and-time-sleep/53589205#53589205) is no more effective and you need to replace it with [*Explicit Wait*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52706693/how-to-combine-implicit-and-explicit-timeouts-in-selenium/52707885#52707885) i.e [*WebDriverWait*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168663/skip-waiting-for-a-website-timer-selenium-python/50168869#50168869)

---

### Solution

So your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Zedas\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
w.get("https://m.uber.com/looking")
WebDriverWait(w, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'"//*[@id="booking-experience-container"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/input"'))).send_keys("test")
```