# Difference between "driver.implicitly_wait(20)" and "WebDriverWait(driver, 20)"

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, implicitwait

I have two questions related to waits.
First, please explain to me what is the difference between the two methods of waiting

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,
'twotabsearchtextbox')))
# and this
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
```

Note that I wrote a code to see the difference before I asked, but the difference was not clear to me
The code you wrote

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import *

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_position(-1200, 0)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://www.amazon.com/");
# driver.implicitly_wait(20)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'twotabsearchtextbox')))
search = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'twotabsearchtextbox')
search.click()
search.send_keys('Laptop hp core i5')
```

The second question is that I sometimes see the WebDriverWait Method assigned to a variable, I mean like this:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'twotabsearchtextbox'))))
```

What is the difference?

I thought WebDriverWait just waits for the item to appear
and the `driver.implicitly_wait(20)` function
Waiting for the page to load.

As for what happened to me, the two methods are waiting for the page to load

Comment: One is an "Implicit" wait and it set globally.  One is an "explicit" wait and is set per action.  Don't mix the two.  See here for full explanation: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Implicit wait

By [*Implicitly waiting*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45674706/7429447), the *WebDriver* instance polls the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) for a certain duration when trying to find any element. This is useful when certain elements on the webpage are not available immediately and need some time to load. Implicit waiting for elements to appear is disabled by default and will need to be manually enabled on a per-session basis. As an example:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

---

### Explicit wait

[*Explicit waits*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50168869/7429447) allows our code to halt program execution, or freeze the thread, until the condition we pass it resolves. The condition is called with a certain frequency until the timeout of the wait is elapsed. This means that for as long as the condition returns a falsy value, it will keep trying and waiting. Thus Explicit waits allows us to wait for a condition to occur which inturn synchronises the state between the browser and its [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes), and the *WebDriver* script. As an example:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'twotabsearchtextbox')))
```

---

### A word of caution

Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can result into unpredictable wait times. As an example, setting an implicit wait of ***10*** seconds and an explicit wait of ***15*** seconds could cause a timeout to occur after ***20*** seconds.