# How to refresh Tableau through a click using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Is there a way to access Tableau viz tool bar buttons like 'Refresh Data in this view' ?
I have tried to locate tool bar elements by id and Xpath both but it throws an element not found exceptions every time.

After loading Tableau viz I am trying to locate the element

```
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
submit_button4 = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'refresh')
submit_button4.click()
```

but throws the below exception:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

HTML snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove [`implicitly_wait()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45674706/7429447) completely replacing it with [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50168869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#refresh"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='refresh']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: tried but didn't work.

Comment: @MuhammadMuhib Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.