# Multiple iframe tags Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, webdriver

I am trying to use selenium to send credit card info onto a site, and each element is contained in a separate iframe tag in the HTML. For example, the box to enter a credit card number is contained in the first iframe tag, and the card holder name is contained in the second iframe, and so on, and so forth. I am able to access the first iframe tag, and send the credit card number into the box, however I an unable to locate the cardholder name iframe tag, and thus cannot send the keys to enter a cardholder name. I'm wondering if there is a way to specifically search for the second (or an arbitrary number other than the first element) iframe tag with webdriver.

Here is the code I used:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
cc = driver.find_element_by_id("number")
cc.send_keys(credit_card_number)
```

This correctly found the first iframe tag which contains the field to enter a card number, and sent the appropriate keys

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
driver.find_element_by_id("name").send_keys(cc_name)
```

This resulted in the following error: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:{"method":"tag name","selector":"iframe"}

[image]

Comment: You need to get specific locator to locate all frame like xpath,id,name. to switch to specific frame after you are in default frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly found the *first iframe tag* which contains the *credit card number* field to enter the card number and sent the appropriate keys. Moving forward when you want to sent the appropriate keys to the *card holder name* field you need to be on the relevant *frame* first. So you have to switch back to the immedediate `parent_frame()` which contains both the *iframe tags* i.e. *first iframe* and *second iframe* and next try to switch to the *second iframe* to locate the *card holder name* field as follows :

```
# as there are multiple frames so find_element_by_tag_name("iframe") will not suffice and have to use unique css/xpath
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_of_iframe1"))
cc = driver.find_element_by_id("number")
cc.send_keys(credit_card_number)
driver.switch_to.default_content() #incase iframe1 and iframe2 are immediate child of the Top Level Content
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_of_iframe2"))
cc = driver.find_element_by_id("name")
cc.send_keys(cc_name)
```

**Note** : As per best practices you should not detect frames through `find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")` inpresence of multiple `<iframe>` tags on the webpage. The best way would be to use either *Frame Name* , *Frame ID* or *Frame Index*. You can find the detailed discussion in [How can I select a html element no matter what frame it is in in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium/47771879#47771879).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. You clearly know more than me about selenium, however I am unable to get my code to work by following your example. With the edit to first switch to the iframe found by xpath, I am unable to locate the element. I also tried with CSS, so it's not an issue with xpath. I updated my post to include an image of the page html which contains the iframe and the element to enter credit card numbers in the body. the iframe and body style is the same for the other fields, so Im assuming the fix should be universal. If you could help me fix this id really appreciate it.

Comment: I ended up fixing my error with the post you linked at the bottom. Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

After switching to first iframe , you have to switch back to default context (your main page containing multiple iframes) & then switch to next iframe .

So your pseudo code should look like

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe_1"))
driver.switch_to.defaultContent()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe_2"))
driver.switch_to.defaultContent()
& so on
```