# Webdriver - How to access to some specific iFrame through xpath/css

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, automation, mocha.js, frontend

I can't access to some iFrame by selenium (node js + mocha) in the website below -

https://www.rt.com/uk/421078-may-skripal-russia-parliament/

The required iframe element -

```
<iframe id="5645d42cb79d139a24d943622da2c47d-iframe" src="https://spoxy-shard5.spot.im/v2/spot/sp_6phY2k0C/post/421078/?elementId=b2ec2c94ee1c35810c76e1704dbe3d06&amp;spot_im_platform=desktop&amp;host_url=https%3A%2F%2Fon.rt.com%2F90wm&amp;host_url_64=aHR0cHM6Ly9vbi5ydC5jb20vOTB3bQ%3D%3D&amp;spot_im_ph__prerender_deferred=true&amp;prerenderDeferred=true&amp;sort_by=best&amp;isStarsRatingEnabled=false&amp;enableMessageShare=true&amp;enableAnonymize=false&amp;isConversationLiveBlog=false&amp;enableSeeMoreButton=true" scrolling="no" style="overflow: hidden; height: 2339px;" data-frame-unique-id="a6cbebb1116a32e10263270bfde7e0c1" data-conversation-id="sp_6phY2k0C_421078"></iframe>
```

I want to send keys to the input elements inside it -

[image]

Please your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch to the specific frame you can use either of the following options :

- CSS :

  ```
  iframe[id$='-iframe'][src^='https://spoxy-shard5.spot.im/v2/spot/sp_']
  ```
- XPATH :

  ```
  //iframe[contains(@id,'-iframe') and starts-with(@src,'https://spoxy-shard5.spot.im/v2/spot/sp_')]
  ```

> **Note** : You may require to induce *wait* for the intended frame to be available and switch to it. You will find a detailed discussion in [How can I select a html element no matter what frame it is in in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium/47771879#47771879). See the **A Better Approach to Switch Frames** section.

Comment: @IdanE Upvote the answer if it was useful to you for the future readers.