# Click on element using selenium python which is under label class

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a web page which i am automating, I can click on any other elements using xpath or name or ID, but this gets little tricky when the element which I want to click is inside label. Here is the example,

```
<div class="dv-widget dv-deco-def dv-sz-med dv-map-sw">
<input name="l_maps" id="grp_perc" value="0" class="map_HD dv-radio-swr" type="radio">
<label for="grp_percentage" class="dv-radio-swl" onclick="">%</label>
<input name="l_maps" id="grp_count" value="1" class="map_HD dv-radio-swr" checked="" type="radio">
<label for="grp_multiply" class="dv-radio-swl" onclick="">*</label></div>
```

I need to click on the radio buton with the text % on it, I tried several option using xpath and CSS and ID but nothing seems to find that element under that label. I need help on this guys please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I tried option like
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='grp_perc']") but that did not help me earlier

Answer (score 0):

To click on the radio button with the text as **%** you can use either of the following lines of code :

- Using `preceding` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@class='dv-radio-swl' and @for='grp_percentage']//preceding::input[1]").click()
  ```
- Using `preceding-sibling` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@class='dv-radio-swl' and @for='grp_percentage']//preceding-sibling::input[1]").click()
  ```
- Using `ancestor` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@class='dv-radio-swl' and @for='grp_percentage']//ancestor::input[1]").click()
  ```

---

### Update

As per the first part of the xpath I have provided it correctly identifies the `<label>` element with text as **%**. See the snapshot :

[image: label_xpath]

Now, appending **preceding** makes no mistake to identify the previous `<input>` tag. See snapshot :

[image: preceding_xpath]

So in all means our *xpath* is correct. Possibly, you need to induce a waiter for the element to be *clickable* as follows :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@class='dv-radio-swl' and @for='grp_percentage']//preceding::input[1]"))).click()
```

If you are still unable to locate the element check the *HTML* if the element is within an `<iFrame>` tag and you will find a detailed discussion in [**How can I select a html element no matter what frame it is in in selenium?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium/47771879#47771879)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried the answer and it did not work. Do you think I should try to click using the type=radio ?

Comment: @Rob Apart from these 2 radio buttons does the page contains more radio buttons?

Comment: no these are the only two radio buttons on this page.

Comment: @Rob Please check my updated answer and let me know the results.

Comment: Hey @DebanjanB thanks for your latest update. I tried you suggestion, I also tried to use the combination of label and preceding-sibling, but the page cannot locate that element. I also tried to see if that element is clickable but selenium doesn't seem to identify that button.

Comment: @Rob Check out my answer update and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a strange situation. Typically the `for` attribute of the `LABEL` matches the ID of the `INPUT` that it corresponds to, e.g.

```
<input id="name" ... >
<label for="name" ... >
```

But in this case it doesn't match. We can get around it pretty easily. You can search for the element that contains the `%` text using XPath and then find the preceding `INPUT`.

```
//label[.='%']/preceding-sibling::input
```

If you plan to use this elsewhere also, I would suggest that you put this into a function and pass in the `LABEL` text, e.g. % and feed that into the locator to click the matching `INPUT`.