# Python Selenium Webdriver: Can I switch to an unfriendly iframe?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I'm getting an error when I try to switch_to_frame() or switch_to.frame() (btw, which of those is correct?) to an unfriendly iFrame. Should that be supported?

```
def click_all(driver):
    for img in imgs:
        img.click()
    iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
    for ifr in iframes:
        try:
            driver.switch_to.frame(ifr)
        except:
            e = sys.exc_info()
            print "Error: %s" % str(e) # Gives a vague error: '(<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException'>, WebDriverException(), <traceback object at 0x1102a9680>)'
            return
        click_all(driver)
```

Thanks for any help!

The stack trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/merrigan/working/DockLion/qe-cordell/test/bases/util.py", 
line 45, in click_all
driver.switch_to_window(ifr)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 657, in switch_to_window
self._switch_to.window(window_name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/switch_to.py", line 113, in window
self._driver.execute(Command.SWITCH_TO_WINDOW, data)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in 
check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 'name' must be a string
(Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506106 
(8a06c39c4582fbfbab6966dbb1c38a9173bfb1a2),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
```

(Does this mean it only works if the iFrame has a name attribute?)

Comment: depending on which version of selenium you're running, `switch_to_frame` is deprecated. also, please provide the full stacktrace of the exception you are encountering. you'll get the output of it by either removing the `try/except` and letting the console print the exception, or using `traceback` and putting `print traceback.format_exc()` in your `except` block

Comment: well, based on the stacktrace... it doesn't appear to be matching the code sample you provided. for example, the 4th line of the stacktrace is: `driver.switch_to_window(ifr)`. also, the very last line of your code seems to cause an infinite loop, but i'm guessing this is just a formatting error of your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass a `WebElement` to the `switch_to.frame` function and it will work.

ex.

```
 driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('id'))
```

The issue you are having above is caused by this line that is not present in your code above:

> self._switch_to.window(window_name)

Which requires a window *name* or *handle*, thus causing your error in the Traceback provided.

If you are still having issues, please provide the relevant **HTML**, so we can help you switch to this frame.

---

`switch_to_frame` is now deprecated, please use `switch_to` for any switching functions.

The documentation on **switching between windows and frames** is [HERE](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames), which refers to `switch_to_frame`, but the description is still relevant for use purposes.

---

**SIDENOTE**

Please update your *Chromedriver* to at **least** `2.36` since you are running on **Chrome build 65**, which is not supported by your current version of *Chromedriver* `2.33`: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

By keeping these up to date, or on a recommended pair, you will run into less problems as described on the chromedriver download landing page.

Comment: as you can tell by his code sample, he is passing a `WebElement` to the `switch_to` function, so that's not the problem. the rest of your answer is about his code not matching the traceback, which has already been noted in a comment onto his post. this answer doesn't provide any answer at all and is more suited for a comment.

Comment: He is directly asking if it should be supported, so I am indeed answering all of his questions stated. He asks in the bottom as well if it can only be switched by name. If you are unhappy with the answer. Please answer yourself.

Comment: you answered the question in his title "can i switch to an unfriendly iframe", in which case, the answer is yes. and a side question about which method is proper. but his question states he has tried both methods and is having an error while trying to do so, which is what he is here trying to get help with. the example you provided is what he is already saying he is trying to do. his traceback, however, shows his code that he is running is not the same he is providing, and that is the problem. so, as said, there isn't a way to provide an answer yet.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that updating the Chromedriver got rid of the error. And thanks for the recommendation to use traceback, @crookedleaf. The test framework was hiding stack traces from me, so this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

While working with frames you need to consider a couple of things as follows :

- An webpage can have multiple frames.
- All the frames may not have distinct `id`, `name`, `class` etc attributes.
- Loading sequence of the *frames* can differ with respect to the *WebElements* with which you interact within the [**Top-Level Browsing Context**](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/browsers.html#windows)
- Some ifames can have the attribute *style* set to **display: none;**

Keeping in view the above mentioned usecases you have to figure out the intended `<iframe>` to which you want to switch. So instead of creating a list through :

```
iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
```

Try to locate the exact frame where the intended *WebElements* are located with which you want to interact through either of the following methods :

```
driver.switch_to.frame("iframe_name") # By Frame Name
driver.switch_to.frame("iframe_id") # By Frame ID
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_index) # By Frame Index
```

You can find a detailed discussion in [**How can I select a html element no matter what frame it is in in selenium?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium/47771879#47771879)

*The API Docs* clearly mentions [**`switch_to_frame()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_frame) method is **Deprecated** :

```
switch_to_frame(frame_reference)
Deprecated use driver.switch_to.frame
```

Use [**`switch_to.frame()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to) instead as follows :

```
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_reference)

Returns : SwitchTo an object containing all options to switch focus into
```

**Note** : For effective *frame switching* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) clause as [`frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it). You can find a detailed discussion under the subheading [**A Better Approach to Switch Frames**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium/47771879#47771879)