# How can locate element which resides in i-frame for selenium script

Tags: selenium

I want to prepare selenium locator for a Text area which reside in I-frame.

How can I locate element through image?

My text area which I want to enter in iframe and i done below code:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("tiny-zps3pdecaq_ifr"); 
Thread.sleep(5000); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tinymce']/p")).sendKeys(Description);
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select a html element no matter what frame it is in in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium)

Comment: Unable to do using same

Comment: Which options did you try out from the other solution? Update the question with the error stack trace for further analysis.

Comment: My text area which i want to enter in iframe and i don ebelow code:
driver.switchTo().frame("tiny-zps3pdecaq_ifr");
Thread.sleep(5000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tinymce']/p")).sendKeys(Description);
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.switchTo().parentFrame();

Comment: Update this information within the question area for an effective analysis.