# Unable to locate element Selenium webdriver || Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="container-fluid ">
<div class="navbar-header">
<span id="problem_hide_search" class="nav navbar-left">
<span id="ca660735dba5d3003d7e5478dc9619b2_title" class="list_search_title navbar-text " style="float: left; display:inherit">Go to</span>
<div style="float: left; display:inherit">
<div class="input-group" style="width: 300px;">
<span class="input-group-addon input-group-select">
<label class="sr-only" for="ca660735dba5d3003d7e5478dc9619b2_text">Search</label>
<input id="ca660735dba5d3003d7e5478dc9619b2_text" class="form-control" name="ca660735dba5d3003d7e5478dc9619b2_text" style="width: 150px;" placeholder="Search"/>
</div>
</div>
<script data-comment="widget search load event">addLoadEvent(function () { new GlideWidgetSearch('ca660735dba5d3003d7e5478dc9619b2', 'problem', 'true'); });</script>
```

Am trying to locate the Search box by switching into iframe and selecting by

```
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*@id="ca660735dba5d3003d7e5478dc9619b2_text"]')
```

But i get error unable to locate Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
Even thought I find one matching node.

Comment: *find one matching node*... Where did you find it? Also let us know whether absent of opening bracket in predicate is a simple typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question that you are *trying to locate the Search box by switching into iframe and selecting* as per the best practices you should :

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the *frame* to be available to switch as follows :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.ID,"id_of_iframe"))
  ```

  Here you will find a detailed discussion [How can I select a html element no matter what frame it is in in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium/47771879#47771879)
- While you look out for an element within an `<iframe>` tag induce *WebDriverWait* with proper [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions). Considering the fact that you intend to send text to the element you can use the following line of code :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='navbar-header']//input[@class='form-control' and contains(@id,'_text')]"))).send_keys("hello")
  ```