# Is there any way to set self driver go to relative parent frameusing Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, frame

Hello i want to set a command where tells to go to relative parent frame using Python & Selenium?

self driver go to relative parent frame  <- this one

Answer (score 0):

To switch focus to the relative parent [*frame*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478) using Python & [*Selenium*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you can use:

```
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
```

If the [*parent frame*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium/47771879#47771879) is the *Top most level context* you can also use:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```