# Why do I get NoSuchElement error when I have a exception in place?

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, error-handling, try-except

I have this could which should check if a iframe is available and swithes to it. Then I have this piece of code that check if a certain element is present.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="stageFrame"]'))) 
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="home_video_js"]')))
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("No video located")
```

I'm not sure why I still get the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="stageFrame"]"}
```

Probably I'm missing something important but I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the line of code for [frame switching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47771879/7429447) is out of the scope of the `try-except{}` block. So it is never handled.

Next, as you have used [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) on failure it should return ***TimeoutException***

Finally, as you are [switching to an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) using the *`id`* attribute to be more canonical you may like to add the ***TAG_NAME*** as well i.e. *`iframe`* . So effective code block will be:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@id="stageFrame"]'))) 
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="home_video_js"]')))
except TimeoutException:
    print("No iframe/video located")
```

Comment: well heres the thing, the iframe i want to switch to is inside the iframe that i have already switched to. The stage ifram doesnt change but the second iframe changes depending on what type of lesson it is. How do i change to a iframe inside another iframe that i already switched too?

Comment: I'm afraid, I don't get you. _`...the iframe i want to switch to is inside the iframe that i have already switched to...`_: we don't know about your first/second iframe. We only see your iframe switching attempt. You may like to raise a new question with all the details of your new requirement.

Comment: I know i make no sense but your suggestion worked ahahah. I havent used selenium in a while and im just confused too. Thanks again for the help

Comment: @Russiahacker Glad to be able to help you.