# NoSuchElementException selecting cell value based on header name by xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I would like to select a cell value with a known row index and selecting it by header name (here "Adjusted Amount")

My code is as follows:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value = f"/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[{2}]/td[th[text()='Adjusted Amount']]/input").get_attribute('value')
```

but still get a *NoSuchElementException*.

Snapshot of the HTML:

[image: This is what the page source looks like]

Comment: what is the URL that you are trying to select this text from? what does the HTML look like? It's hard to diagnose a problem just based on what you have given.

Comment: I cannot share the link, but I just uploaded the post with a screenshot of the HTML source.

Comment: it doesn't look like there are any `th[text()='Adjusted Amount']` in the HTML that you show. Are you trying to select the input source below the Adjusted Amount header? (could you also show that element in the HTML)

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Comment: It's impossible for anyone to test and debug your XPath without access to the actual HTML which is your source data. A picture of the data is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the HTML:

[image: html]

There are a couple of issues in your line of code which you need to address as follows:

- The element with text ***Adjusted Amount*** is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired [*`frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47771879/7429447).

  ```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#WorkArea")))
  ```
- The element with text ***Adjusted Amount*** isn't within any `<th>` but within `<td>`. So to reference the `<td>` element ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form[name*='TotalBondCalculation table table > tbody > tr td:nth-child(7)']")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//form[contains(@name, 'TotalBondCalculation')]//table//table/tbody/tr//td[text()='Adjusted Amount']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```