# How to locate the username field within an iframe with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I'm trying to access a city hall portal using Selenium, but I'm having difficulties filling in the login details. I'm trying to use XPath as a way to locate the elements, but I'm not having success. The website I'm working with is: https://directa.natal.rn.gov.br/open.do?sys=DIR&a=wqf45tfes

I'm trying to fill in the *username* and *password* fields. I would appreciate any tips on how to proceed because the usual XPath method that works on other websites is not successful in this case.

I used the following attempt:

```
usuario = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="usuario"]')
```

Comment: What exactly does "not successful" mean?  If you're getting an error, or unexpected results, you have to **show them to us**.  Otherwise we are just guessing at the actual problem.

Comment: Also, show us the html code for the element on the page that you expected to find.

Comment: Also, since you know the item id, why bother using xpath?  `find_element(By.ID, "usuario")` is much more direct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Xpath for selecting username:

```
//input[@id='usuario']
usuario = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@id='usuario']')
```

for password field:

```
//input[@id='senha']
senha = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@id='senha']')
```

for Submit button:

```
//button[@id='acessar']
acessar= browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[@id='acessar']')
```

you should first send the username and password and then click the acessar button.
hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To send a character sequence to the *username* and *password* field as the elements are within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*`frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47771879/7429447).
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://directa.natal.rn.gov.br/open.do?sys=DIR&a=qxG6rejnY45ft")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"frame[name='mainsystem']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#usuario"))).send_keys("João Felipe")
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#senha").send_keys("João Felipe")
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://directa.natal.rn.gov.br/open.do?sys=DIR&a=qxG6rejnY45ft")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//frame[@name='mainsystem']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='usuario']"))).send_keys("João Felipe")
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='senha']").send_keys("João Felipe")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Felipe]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)