# Automate Login with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, python-requests

I am trying to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to log into a printer and conduct some tests. I really do not have much experience with this process and have found it somewhat confusing.

First, to get values that I may have wanted I opened the printers web page in Chrome and did a right click "view page source"  - This turned out to be not helpful. From here I can only see a bunch of `<script>` tags that call some .js scripts. I am assuming this is a big part of my problem.

Next I selected the "inspect" option after right clicking. From here I can see the actual HTML that is loaded. I logged into the site and recorded the process in Chrome. With this I was able to identify the variables which contain the Username and Password. I went to this part of the HTML did a right click and copied the Xpath. I then tried to use the Selenium `find_element_by_xpath` but still no luck. I have tried all the other methods to (find by ID, and name) however it returns an error that the element is not found.

I feel like there is something fundamental here that I am not understanding. Does anyone have any experience with this???

Note: I am using Python 3.7 and Selenium, however I am not opposed to trying something other than Selenium if there is a more graceful way to accomplish this.

My code looks something like this:

**EDIT**
Here is my updated code - I can confirm this is not just a time/wait issue. I have managed to successfully grab the first two outer elements but the second I go deeper it errors out.

```
def sel_test():
    chromeOptions = Options()
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
    url = 'http://<ip address>/'
    browser.get(url)
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ccrx-root"]')))

    finally: browser.quit()
```

The element that I want is buried in this tag - Maybe this has something to do with it? Maybe related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732549/python-selenium-webdriver-navigating-nested-frame-sets)

```
<frame name="wlmframe" src="../startwlm/Start_Wlm.htm?arg11=">
```

Comment: If I'm understanding, you'd like to automate log-in to a url to avoid having to manually enter user/pass information? That's generally not good practice as it undermines security. That said, I have seen it implemented successfully by creating environment variables (eg, printerUSER, printerPASS) and pushing them to the appropriate user/pass webpage element.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML?  That'll help eliminate some common pitfalls (e.g. element is in `<iframe>`)...

Comment: If you're dealing with JS you may want to add some wait time in there to let the page fully load.

Comment: @Hatt  this was my first suspicion. I did add a short 30 second timer in there to determine if this may be the issue and still didn't work. Maybe it needs longer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732549/python-selenium-webdriver-navigating-nested-frame-sets) you can only work with the current frame which is seen. You need to tell selenium to switch frames in order to access child frames.

For example:
`browser.switch_to.frame('wlmframe')`

This will then load the nested content so you can access the children

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is most likely do to either the element not loading on the page until after your bot searches for it, or a pop-up changing the xpath of the element.

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

delay = 3 # seconds
try:
    elementUsername = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.xpath, 'element-xpath')))

    element.send_keys('your username')

except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")
```

you can find out more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/wait-until-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-webdriver-for-python)

Comment: this code doesn't work as written. Is this for Python2 maybe?

Comment: I mostly copied this code from the link at the end of my answer.  I personally use selenium with node.js so I can't tell you for sure.

Comment: it's using python2 syntax for `print`